# Saving object with has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a place model that has_many categories through category_tags. 
I have a validation on tags to ensure that it has a place and a category as well as to avoid having the same category twice on a place.

Models:

```
class PlaceCategory < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :place_category_tags, inverse_of: :place_category
  has_many :places, through: :place_category_tags

end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :place_category_tags, inverse_of: :place
  has_many :place_categories, through: :place_category_tags

end

class PlaceCategoryTag < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :place
  belongs_to :place_category

  validates :place_id, presence: true
  validates :place_category_id, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :place_id}

end
```

I also have an index on my place_category_tags table, to ensure the uniqueness at the database level:

```
add_index "place_category_tags", ["place_id", "place_category_id"], name: "index_place_category_tags_on_place_id_and_place_category_id", unique: true, using: :btree
```

My problem is when I save a new place with tags. The validation is performed on tags before saving the place, so it fails because place_id is blank.

```
2.1.5 :001 > place = Place.new()
 => #<Place id: nil, name: "erg", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.1.5 :002 > place.place_category_tags.build(place_category_id: 3)
 => #<PlaceCategoryTag id: nil, place_id: nil, place_category_id: 3, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.1.5 :003 > place.save
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  PlaceCategoryTag Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "place_category_tags"  WHERE ("place_category_tags"."place_category_id" = 3 AND "place_category_tags"."place_id" IS NULL) LIMIT 1
  PlaceCategoryTag Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "place_category_tags"  WHERE ("place_category_tags"."place_category_id" = 3 AND "place_category_tags"."place_id" IS NULL) LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
 => false 
2.1.5 :004 > place.errors
 => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x0000000384e8a8 @base=#<Place id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:"place_category_tags.place_id"=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

I searched for similar issues but what I found was that I had to add the inverse_of option on my place's has_many place_category_tags, which I did, but it didn't solve my problem.

I also tried to perform the validation on place and place_category instead of place_id and place_category_id:

```
validates :place, presence: true
validates :place_category, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :place}
```

That seems to work, but the problem is that the uniqueness validation is no longer performed when I try to create two identical place_category_tags, and I get an error at the database level:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_place_category_tags_on_place_id_and_place_category_id"
DETAIL:  Key (place_id, place_category_id)=(49, 3) already exists.
: INSERT INTO "place_category_tags" ("created_at", "place_category_id", "place_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"):
  app/controllers/backend/places_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

Does someone have an idea of what's wrong with my code?

Also, I find the fact that the validation is skipped altogether in the second example very weird. If someone had an idea of what's going on, that'd be great :)

edit: I'm using Rails 4.1.8 and ruby 2.1.5p273

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you write in console:

```
place = Place.new()
place.place_category_tags.build(place_category_id: 3)
place.place_category_tags.first.place
```

In case the inverse_of is working it should return your the new place.

In the first example it looks like your `place_id`is se to `nil`.
In the second example it appears to be valid numbers that are duplicate.

Perhaps it is easier to try around with it if you remove the `unique: true` tag on the index-migration.

I do think that you should use the validation on the objects and not the ID's.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`validates_associated`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-associated) helper method for validation.

ActiveRecord validates objects before saving to database so you don't have to validate it again on the database side.

In your case it will check whether a place is valid and then validate its tags. But you'll need the place to be created (to have an id) before building tags on it, so use `Place.create` instead of `Place.new` as [Sharvy Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3425360/sharvy-ahmed) suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Using `create` instead of `new` will solve your problem. This will ensure place has an `id` before building associated objects.

```
place = Place.create
place.place_category_tags.build(place_category_id: 3)
place.save
```

Comment: Yes, this works because the place is already created and has an id, but in my case, I call new in the new action and then create the place in the create acion of my controller. Tags are passed as nested attributes in the form.